# OnItemClickedListener for ListView not working

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I have searched through most of stackOverflow regarding this but I haven't been able to find a working solution for this problem that's seem to pop up in android a lot. Any help would be appreciated.

The main requirement is for me to get the index of the listItem that was clicked .

I have a **setOnItemClickListener()** which does not work when the underlying listItem is clicked.

My listItem has a LinearLayout at it's root, on which a **onClickListener()** is set .

On debugging this, the **onItemClickListener()** does trigger, but very very rarely. Maybe **1 in 100** clicks trigger the **onItemClickListener()**. This needs to happen consistently.

If there is no OnClickListener set on the ListItem, then the onItemClicked is triggered every time.

Here is my listItem xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/poll_option_row_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/radio_button_image"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/poll_option"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="TestText 1"
            android:background="@color/design_default_color_error"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:thumb="@null"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/poll_option_summary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:text="Item Divider"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is xml for the mainActivity which contains the ListView :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the CustomAdapter code :

```
package com.example.testlistview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    protected final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private  List<String> strings;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> strings) {
        this.strings = strings;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout listItemLayout;
        SeekBar seekBar;
        ImageView radioButton;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return strings.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int i) {
        return strings.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = createConvertView();
        }

        bindView(strings.get(position), convertView);

        return convertView;
    }

    protected void bindView(final String string, View convertView) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        viewHolder.seekBar.setEnabled(false);

        viewHolder.listItemLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Perform some action
            }
        });

    }

    private View createConvertView() {
        View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        setViewHolderViews(viewHolder, convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        return convertView;
    }

    private void setViewHolderViews(ViewHolder viewHolder, View convertView) {
        viewHolder.listItemLayout = convertView.findViewById(R.id.poll_option_row_layout);
        viewHolder.seekBar = convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        viewHolder.radioButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.radio_button_image);
    }

}
```

And the MainActivity code :

```
package com.example.testlistview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Dummy Data not used anywhere
        listItems.add("apple");
        listItems.add("ball");
        listItems.add("cat");
        listItems.add("dog");
        listItems.add("elephant");

        listView=findViewById(R.id.listView);

        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                //Perform necessary actions

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need `onItemClick` as well as the regular `onClick` on an item..? The reason why `onItemClick` doesn't get called has to do with the other view "consuming" the click event. Basically the layout reports that it handled the click event, so it doesn't get propagated further.

Comment: @Vucko , I need to get the  position of the listItem that was clicked . 
Is there a way to get the index of listItem clicked without implementing ```onItemClick()``` ?

Comment: If that's the case, you can actually just pass the `position` parameter from `getView` method and have that index like that. Also, I've not used a `ListView` in like 3 years, it's all been replaced with `RecyclerView`, might wanna look into that.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

delete them or set it to true in your listitem.xml